# How to properly do a GMP bit shift?

Tags: c, gmp

I need to do some calculations with huge precision integers and want to use the GMP library. I was hoping that there is someone experienced with it here because I don't understand how to use the bit shifts. I was trying it with the code below. The code compiles but b still contains 0.

https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions

```c
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#include <gmp.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
int main()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    mpz_t a;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    mpz_t b;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    mpz_init2(b, a->_mp_size);                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    mpz_set_str(a, "1", 16);                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    mp_limb_t bits = mpn_lshift(b->_mp_d, &a->_mp_d[0], a->_mp_size, 1);                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    gmp_printf("%Zx\n", a);                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    gmp_printf("Bits shifted %M\n", bits);                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    gmp_printf("%Zd", b);                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

Comment: `a->_mp_size` is uninitialized and contains garbage. Did you compile your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O` ?

Comment: mpz_init_set_str(a, "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16);

Comment: Oops I just deleted the initialiazation for a while editing. Wait a sec..

Comment: Do you really want to use these low level functions?

Comment: Nah, that is not the problem. a prints fine. The shift does not work.

Comment: @kelalaka Well, I want to do bit shifts like ``>>`` and ``<<``. I have not found another shift function in the GMP library. So I guess that is what I need to do.

Comment: Did you see `mpz_mul_2exp`?

Comment: If you want the equivalent of `<<` and `>>`, you can look at how those 2 operators are implemented in the C++ gmpxx.h (they call mpz_mul_2exp and mpz_fdiv_q_2exp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below code uses `mpz_fdiv_q_2exp` for the right shift and `mpz_mul_2exp` for the left shift together with `mpz_tdiv_r_2exp`. `mpz_tdiv_r_2exp` is necessary since the size increases when data multiplied.

```c
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#include <gmp.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                 

int main()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    mpz_t a;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    mpz_t b;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    mpz_init_set_str(a, "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16);                                                                                                                                                                                  
              
    for ( int i = 0; i < 128;  i++) {
        
        //left shift
        mpz_mul_2exp(b,a,I);
        //This is faster than `mpz_mod` since we are in 2^128 
        mpz_tdiv_r_2exp(b,b,128);
        
        //right shift
        //mpz_fdiv_q_2exp( b,a,i);     
    
        gmp_printf("\n%#40Zx", b); 
    }
    
    gmp_printf("\n%Zd", a);
    
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

Some part of the output

```
      0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
      0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffe
      0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffc
      ...
      0xe0000000000000000000000000000000
      0xc0000000000000000000000000000000
      0x80000000000000000000000000000000
```

[GMP manual page 35](https://gmplib.org/gmp-man-6.2.1.pdf)

> For positive n both mpz_fdiv_q_2exp and mpz_tdiv_q_2exp are simple bitwise right shifts.

**Note**: It is possible to use `mpn_lshift` and `mpn_rshift` directly, however, this will require more coding and testing under the development library. How it is more complex can be seen from [mpz_mul_2exp](https://github.com/alisw/GMP/blob/2bbd52703e5af82509773264bfbd20ff8464804f/mpz/mul_2exp.c#L35)'s source code.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at it tomorrow and then verify, if it works. Very tired now :)

Comment: The mod is necessary since the left shift by mpz_mul_2exp makes it larger!

Comment: Just ran it. Seems to do what is expected. I just wonder why the GMP team hasn't implemented a simpler function. I have been searching the manual for hours.

Comment: You could propose a patch to the GMP team and library

Comment: Well, I ran before post. Both are defined as mentioned with bitwise shifts. I think they consider this as a shift. The `mpn_lshift` is low level and here see how [mpz_mul_2exp](https://github.com/alisw/GMP/blob/2bbd52703e5af82509773264bfbd20ff8464804f/mpz/mul_2exp.c#L35) implemented. It is already low level, only the mod is missing. Of course, a little faster implementation can be done.

Comment: Made it faster by using `mpz_tdiv_r_2exp`

Comment: Thanks! Do you use GMP at work? It is really a super interesting library.

Comment: Well, I use whatever need and that depends on where do you coding and what you need. PHP and Perl also support GMP.

Comment: So from what I understand, I need ``mpz_mul_2exp()`` and ``mpz_tdiv_r_2exp()`` to complete one shift operation? Ah yes, could have tried it out earlier actually.

Comment: Yes, since the multiplication makes the number larger than necessary. Be careful, on the other hand the division makes it smaller.

Comment: I already found that out. So I used ``mpz_mul_2exp()`` and ``mpz_and(b,b,a)`` instead. This is exactly what I need. I think I can wrap this in a function somehow. Pity than you have to use a temporary variable here can can't use ``mpz_mul_2exp(a,a,1)``

Comment: Yes, that is another way to do that. Need a performance comparison, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232035/discussion-between-neolith-and-kelalaka).